# Add playlist button in integration guidelines not working

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm trying to create a button that add the current view as a playlist like this

```
<button class="add-playlist button icon" value="spotify:album:0fqSVcXza5It71LS2BJdLR"><span class="plus"></span>Add as Playlist</button><br />
```

But nothing happens when I click on that button.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a HTML button will not do the work for you.
You need to use [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) as well.

If you are building an app inside the Spotify client, something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
var subscribeToPlaylist: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var button = this,
        models = require('sp://import/scripts/api/models'),
        playList = models.Playlist.fromURI(this.value);

    playList.subscribed = true;
};

var myButton = document.querySelector('button.add-playlist');

myButton.onclick = subscribeToPlaylist;
```

For this to work you need to use it with the Spotify Apps API

Check out the Spotify Apps API here: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/